# Error on Indy HTTP post using TStringList as sending parameter

Tags: delphi, indy

I have created a little program which access a webservice of mail service. The same code works on Delphi 7 with indy 9, but doesn't works with Delphi Seattle with Indy 10.

My Stringlist is built that way:

```
  ParametrosConsulta.Values['nCdEmpresa']   := Edt_Cod.Text;
  ParametrosConsulta.Values['&sDsSenha']    := Edt_Sen.Text;
  ...
```

My post have a sending parameter a stringlist, which has a text like that:

```
nCdEmpresa= &sDsSenha= &nCdServico=41106&sCepOrigem=88905355&sCepDestino=88906768&nVlPeso=20.0&nCdFormato=1&nVlComprimento=20.0&nVlAltura=20.0&nVlLargura=20.0&nVlDiametro=6.0&sCdMaoPropria=N&nVlValorDeclarado=0&sCdAvisoRecebimento=N
```

then i call idHttp.Post like that, which `ParametroConsulta` holds the text i've shown before, and `Resposta` is a TStringStream which holds the response of the request:

```
   IdHttp.Request.Clear;
   IdHttp.Request.Host := 'ws.correios.com.br';
   IdHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
   idHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible;Indy Library)';
   IdHTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';
   IdHTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
   {...}
   try
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      FrmPrincipal.Refresh;
      IdHttp.Post('http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo', ParametrosConsulta, Resposta);
   except
      on E:EIdHttpProtocolException do
      begin
         ShowMessage(E.Message + ' - ' + E.ErrorMessage);
         PnlEnviando.Visible := False;
         Exit;
      end;
   end;
```

But after post, the webservice returns that `sDsSenha` is missing (this parameter can hold a empty space).

Comment: How do you build the parameter collection? Through `DelimitedText`?

Comment: @Victoria i'm using key and value

Comment: Do not use `&` char. Indy concatenate parameters for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write `&`:

```
ParametrosConsulta.Values['sDsSenha']    := Edt_Sen.Text;
```

Ampersand are adding by Indy automatically. <s>Btw, you may need to  use `TIdURI.PathEncode(Edt_Sen.Text)` for escaping some characters.</s>

Comment: You don't need to encode parameters. So long they get into the collection, they will be encoded by Indy.

Comment: Yes, forgot about that.

Comment: @Victoria: only if the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag is enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property (which it is by default).